# Finding one solution of second order DE using another solution using Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, homogeneous-equation, wronskian

I want to check whether following method works in general for finding a solution of the $2^{nd}$ order DE when one solution is given.

$$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$

Let $y_1$ be a solution of the DE and assume that $y_2=v(x)\cdot y_1$ is a solution where $v(x)$ is a function of $x$ and not any constant in $\mathbb{R}$.
Hence $y_1$ and $y_2$ will be linearly independent thus making the Wronskian non-zero. Thus,
$$\begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2'
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & v\cdot y_1 \\ y_1' & v\cdot y_1' +v'\cdot y_1
\end{vmatrix}\neq 0\\
\therefore\ v'y_1^2=c_1,\qquad c_1\in \mathbb{R}\\
\therefore\ dv=c_1(y_1^{-2})dx\\
\therefore\ v=c_1\int \frac{dx}{y_1^2}\\
\therefore\ y_2=y_1c_1\int \frac{dx}{y_1^2}\\
\therefore\ y_2=y_1c_1\cdot (I +c_2)$$

So, the only question that remains is finding $c_1\ \&\ c_2$ which can be found by putting some constraints, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wronskian of this ODE
$$y''+Py'+Qy=0~~~~(1)$$
is given as
$$y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2=\exp[-\int P dx]$$
Let $y_2(x)=v(x)y_1(x)$, then it follows that
$$v'y_1^2=\exp[-\int P dx] \implies v=\int \frac{\exp[-\int {P dx}]}{y_1^2} dx~~~(2)$$
Hence if $y_1$ is one solution of (1), then $y_2(x) = v(x) y_1$ is its other solution. The total (general) solution is given by $y(x)=C_1y_1(x)+C_2 v(x) y_1(x)$, where $C_1, C_2$ are calculated by the additional given particular conditions in a question.

Note that OP's expression for $v(x)$ is incorrect, it should be as given in (2).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: So now you may accept the answer.